# Nodejs: Using i18n-2 Client side or Server side or both

Tags: angularjs, node.js, internationalization, locale

I'm developing a proyect in nodejs, I want to add a feature for language translation.

Checking on internet i saw 2 options that seem ok (i18n and i18n-2).

I have added the proper code in my server side in order to configure it.

In express.js

```
var i18n = require('i18n-2');


i18n.expressBind(app, {
// setup some locales - other locales default to vi silently
locales: ['es', 'en'],
// set the default locale
defaultLocale: 'en',
// set the cookie name
cookieName: 'locale',
extension: ".json"
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
req.i18n.setLocaleFromQuery();
req.i18n.setLocaleFromCookie();
next();
});
```

So if in this same file I put this code below, it's suppose to print in english language because of the defaultLocale but it prints in Spanish

```
var i18n2 = new (require('i18n-2'))({
locales: ['es', 'en'],
// set the default locale
defaultLocale: 'en',
// set the cookie name
cookieName: 'locale',
extension: ".json"
});
console.log("Mensaje de i18n");
console.log( i18n2.__("hola") );
```

Apart of this question, I want to know how I can send this i18n variable to the client side in order to use it in the views of templates or if I have to create another one.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that defaultLocale option is not used during object initialization. You can check [here](https://github.com/jeresig/i18n-node-2/blob/master/i18n.js#L63) how this lib doing it. just taking the first el from the locales array. So if you put 'en' language at 1st, it will work properly.